# How to disable certian logs in apache config

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

I tried to disable  AWS ELB logs in apache logs .

I am doing this

`SetEnvIf User-agent "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" skiplog`

`CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined env=!skiplog`

But its not working , it still logs

This is the log message

```
10.50.10.89 - - [16/Jun/2018:00:41:14 +0200] "GET /healthcheck.php HTTP/1.1" 200 30228 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the *env apache module*.

```
a2enmod env
```

Don't log requests made by  AWS ELB.

```
SetEnvIFNoCase User-Agent "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" dontlog
```

You have to restart the apache service.

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/setenvif_apache2 seems to have additional information related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition uses the wRoNg CaSe it should be `User-Agent`